# Zero-sum games being converted into positive-sum games

Tags: philosophy-of-economics, adam-smith

It seems as if "pure, naked self-interest", that is, self-interest without liberty, results often in a zero-sum game. (I'm using the term liberty in a Lockean sense, where it is taken to mean the presence of wise regulations that actually enhances our freedoms).

Therefore, it also appears that the presence of such regulations have a role in the harnessing of self-interest for the common good, where a zero-sum game is essentially converted into a positive-sum game.

I'm curious if this line of analysis has been explored in the literature. Any references to articles in the literature are welcome and would be much appreciated.

Comment: I realize that this is a big topic, but I'm looking for mainly for game-theoretic models, maybe in the area of mechanism design.